# Redeploying Databricks Asset Bundle fails due to duplicate name

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables, databricks-asset-bundle

I created a Databricks Asset Bundle and it seems it is successfully being deployed with the `databricks bundle deploy` command. When I run the same command again with the same bundle I get the error

> The pipeline name 'mypipeline' is already used by another pipeline. This check can be skipped by setting `allow_duplicate_names = true` in the request.

1. allow_duplicate_names seems to be a parameter in databricks api but I can't find a corresponding parameter in databricks cli
2. Is allowing duplicate names even the right way to go? I think that might create a new pipeline with the same name instead of updating the existing one

Comment: How much time did you wait after you deleted your pipeline and tried recreating it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I was both testing this from my own command line, using my own credentials, and the service principal used by our deployment pipeline. So first I deployed from my machine and then from the deployment pipeline. Seems like the pipelines are connected somehow to the user that created them. So as long as it's the same user deploying everything worked fine.